# How to work with Core Data saving JSON response,Show data when internet is offline in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I have already parsed `JSON` and showing in `tableView` which is working fine. Now my question is how will i save data offline and show when internet is not available offline using `Core Data`. I am working in Swift 3. If anyone can help me with screenshot it will be great help.
Below is my Code for fetching json and showing on `tableView` :

```
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration

struct CellData {

    var name:String
    var address:String

    public init(name:String,address:String){

        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}

///ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewData: UITableView!

    var arrayData = [CellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
            print("Internet Connection Available!")
            fetchServerData()


        }else{

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet connection", message: "Please ensure you are connected to the Internet", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Internet Connection not Available!")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCellData

        cell.lblTop.text = "\(arrayData[indexPath.row].name)"
        cell.lblBottom.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].address

        return cell
    }


    func fetchServerData(){

        let prs = [
            "author_id": "1780",
            "get_deals_author": "1" as String
        ]
        Service.StartWithoutLoading(prs as [String : AnyObject]?, onCompletion: { result in

            let json = result as? NSDictionary
            if let data = json as? [String:Any]{
                if let err = data["status"] as? String, err == "success"{
                    if let data = data["result"] as? [Any]{

                        var arrayData = [CellData]()

                        for sectionObj in data{
                            if let sectionObjVal = sectionObj as? [String:Any]{

                                if let name_deal = sectionObjVal["name"] as? String{
                                    if let address_deal = sectionObjVal["address"] as? String{

                                        let dataValue = CellData.init(name: name_deal, address: address_deal)

                                        arrayData.append(dataValue)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in

                            self.arrayData.removeAll()
                            self.arrayData = arrayData
                            self.tableViewData.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Core Data, you need to create the entities you need in CoreData model `.xcdatamodeld`. 
 Click on Add Entity and name your entity. Then add attributes which you require to save.

[image]

You can see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW2) on how to create the entities and attributes. After creating everything, we can write a `CoreDataStack` and a manager class or we can directly use the code pre-written in AppDelegate when we check on Core Data when creating a project. I'll here use the `CoreDataStack` class.

Here is the class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack: NSObject {

    static let moduleName = "YourProject"
    static let shared = CoreDataStack()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        _ = self.persistentContainer
    }

    func saveContext () {
            let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {

                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: CoreDataStack.moduleName)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            print("Coordinator URL - \(storeDescription)")
        })
        return container
    }()
}
```

Now we can make a manager class to insert the data. Let's say your entity is `Person` and its attributes are `name` and `address`

Here is the `CoreDataManager` class to insert, update, fetch data.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager: NSObject {

    class func addRecord(object:[String:Any]) {
        let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext) as! Person
        person.name = object["name"] as? String
        person.address = object["address"] as? String
        CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()
    }

   class func getRecords() -> [Person]? {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let results = try CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
            return results
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
       return nil
    }
}
```

You can call `addRecord` method in your `ViewController` class and it will save your data. I recommend that you pass the complete array and then add in core data and finally call `saveContext()`.

Finally you can use `getRecords` to get all records.

Comment: still unable to understand i created entity with "name" & "address"

Comment: You don’t have to create separate entities. Single entity with name as Person and their attributes as name and address. Check core data tutorials first in order to understand how core data works

Comment: Insert them in core data. What else?